# Merge lists with different size. Fill with smallest

Tags: python

I was wondering if is any module that does the following:

```
A = [ A, B, C ]
B = [ 24 ]

C = [ (24, A ), ( 24, B ) , (24, C) ]
```

Thanks

Comment: This is underspecified in the general case; say `B = [24, 35]`.  What would you want `C` to become?

Comment: This is specific case. Just with one element in B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> B = [24]

>>> import itertools
>>> list(zip(itertools.cycle(B), A))
[(24, 'A'), (24, 'B'), (24, 'C')]
```

---

If your `B` is `['24']`, not `[24]`, try:

```
>>> A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> B = ['24']

>>> import itertools
>>> list(zip(itertools.cycle(map(int, B)), A))
[(24, 'A'), (24, 'B'), (24, 'C')]
```

I think you know the difference between int object and str object...

Comment: For some reason I get this: [('2', 'A'), ('4', 'B'), ('2', 'C')]

Comment: Looks like your `B` is `'24'`, not `24`. Try `list(zip(itertools.cycle(map(int, B)), A))`

Comment: Thanks mate. Sry Im quite new to Python

Answer (score 2):

Without any external modules required, this would work for the specific case:

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C']
B = [24]
C = zip(B * len(A), A)
print C

[(24, 'A'), (24, 'B'), (24, 'C')]
```

Comment: For some reason I get this: [('2', 'A'), ('4', 'B'), ('2', 'C')]

Comment: @andresAlvarado You won't get that output if you use the code as I have provided (including the assignment to `A` and `B`).  I can replicate your output only if `B` is a string literal (i.e., `B = '24'`) which is not a *list*, as indicated in your question.